# QGIS 3.4.1 crash without error after opening "options" (18.04. Bionic Beaver)

Tags: qgis-3

QGIS 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. crashes without error after opening "options". I uninstalled all plugins and reinstalled QGIS (purge, autoremove, install...)

Comment: Try moving any ~/.qgis* or .local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/* stuff out of the way.

Comment: Okay, did that... but now I get lot installation process errors while trying to reinstall QGIS. Like this: 'dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libqgisgrass7-3.2.3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed'

Answer (score -1):

I having same problem with QGIS 3.4.1 on windows 10, but without doing anything. It crash without notice. It is seems that happens when any process starts and look for memory.

Comment: Well, too many people are reporting crash with QGIS 3.4.1 doing whatever a task. Yesterday I saw a new message like this: no video memory, I think QGIS 3.4 is having a mayor bug.